# push ajax response to array in angularJs

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I have a function with the array objects.

```
$http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: 'select.php'
     }).then(function success(response) {
          alert(response);
          //$scope.posts=response.data; 
     }, function error(response) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
     }
);
function store() {    
    this.products = [        
       new product("APL", "Apple", "Eat one every…", 12, 90, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2),
       new product("AVC", "Avocado", "Guacamole…", 16, 90, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2),
       new product("BAN", "Banana", "These are…", 4, 120, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2)           
    ];

}
```

In the above code we are passing some static data, but instead i am trying to a push some dynamic data which comes from another file as a ajax response.

so how can i make it dynamic. i have tried like this

```
function store() {
this.products = [    
    //new product("APL", "Apple", "Eat one every…", 12, 90, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2),
    //new product("AVC", "Avocado", "Guacamole…", 16, 90, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2),
    //new product("BAN", "Banana", "These are…", 4, 120, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2)
    $scope.product.push(response.data);
];
}
```

but its not working. any idea how can i make it?

Comment: You have to put $scope.product.push(response.data); in the success of ajax request

Comment: $scope.products, not $scope.product, in case you hadn't noticed the typo

Comment: new product(), this one should be repeated depend on total row of data right?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below code:

```
$scope.products = [];
    $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: 'select.php'
                }).then(function success(response) {
                    $scope.store(response.data);
                  }, function error(response) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                  });

$scope.store = function(data){
  $scope.products.push(data); 
}
```

Comment: ok then what should i write here in this.products = [
    
       new product()   ]}

Comment: function store() {
    this.products = [
    
       //new product("APL", "Apple", "Eat one every…", 12, 90, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2),
      
     $scope.products.push(response.data);
     

   }

Comment: I have edited my code, have look at it. It will automatically push your new data object to the array.

Comment: this is the error i am getting in the console $scope is not defined and store is not defined.

Comment: Can u post with the controller injection. or you update in some js fiddle.

Comment: I dont find any http service call in fiddle?.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to populate the store with items asynchronously, you need to re-factor the store controller to work with promises:

```
function storeController($scope, $routeParams, DataService) {

  // get store from service
  ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶D̶a̶t̶a̶S̶e̶r̶v̶i̶c̶e̶.̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶;̶

  var promise = DataService.getStore();

  promise.then(function(store) {
      $scope.store = store;
      return store;
  }).then(function(store) {
      // use routing to pick the selected product
      var sku = $routeParams.productSku
      if ( sku != null) {
        $scope.product = DataService.getProduct(store, sku);
      };
  });
}
```

Then `DataService` needs to return a promise:

```
storeApp.service("DataService", function($http) {
  ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶m̶y̶S̶t̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶(̶)̶;̶

  ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶m̶y̶S̶t̶o̶r̶e̶;̶
  this.getStore = _getStore;
  this.getProduct = _getProduct;

  var dataPromise;
  function _getStore() { 
    if (! dataPromise) {
        dataPromise = getData();
    };   
    return dataPromise.then(function(data) {
       return data.map(item => new product(item));
    });
  }

  function getData() {
    var url = 'select.php';
    return $http.get(url)
      .then(function success(response) {
        return response.data; 
    }).catch(function error(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        console.log("ERROR: ",response.status);
        throw response;
    });
  }

  function _getProduct(products, sku) {
      for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].sku == sku)
          return products[i];
      }
      return null;
  }
});
```

Avoid putting constructor functions such as `store` on global scope. In addition to cluttering global scope, they can't take advantage of AngularJS services such as `$http`. Instead encapsulate those functions in AngularJS services which can then inject other services.